# Rails - Controller error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, typeerror

just getting a really weird error and was wondering if anyone could enlighten me as to what is going on.

First of all here is my code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def index
    list
    render("list")
end#end index
def new
    @user = User.new
end#end new
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @page.save
        flash[:notice] = "Page Created Successfully!"
        redirect_to(:action => 'list')
    else
        render('new')
    end#if else
end#end create
def list
    @list = User.order('users.position ASC')
end#end list
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end#end show
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end#end edit
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:page])
        flash[:notice] = "Page updated Successfully"
        redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @user.id)
    else
        render('edit')
    end#end if else
end#end update
def delete
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end#end delete
def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = "User has been removed"
    redirect_to(:action => 'list')
end#end destroy
end#end class
```

I am getting a type error when I run the server and go to http://localhost:3000/users/new

NameError in UsersController#new

uninitialized constant UsersController::User
Rails.root: C://Documents/Programming/Ruby Files/kccoding

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in 'new'

But I don't see myself trying to do that at all... AND I am getting no line numbers as to where this error is coming from... Any suggestions?

Kelan

EDIT ~~~ I changed the variables to User.<>, but I'm getting an "uninitialized constant UsersController::User" error. It is in whichever method I am trying to call.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
render('new')
```

It should be:

```
render :action => 'new'
```

Try that in your `new` method.

Answer (score 0):

You sure it's not `User.new` that you want.

```
def new
    @user = User.new
end#end new
```

Comment: I was getting an uninitialized constant UsersController::User error when I did that, so I'm not sure...

Comment: Did you define a User model in app/models/user.rb?

Comment: Yup, I have a whole bunch about creating passwords and such in there

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Users.new you need to type:

```
def new
    @user = User.new
end#end new
```

Check for proper model name everywhere in controller (Users => User)

Comment: I was getting an uninitialized constant UsersController::User error when I did that, so I'm not sure..

Comment: So, whats name of your User model?

Comment: Do you have appropriate routes in config/routes.rb (resources :users)?

Comment: I have the catch all one activated  "match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'" as well as get 'users/new'

Answer (score 0):

It seems error doesn't just come from controller code.
Do post you error trace from log files, something can be found from that only.